# fcgid, fastcgi with or without php-fpm?

Tags: apache, php, mod-fcgid

I'm installing Apache 2.4.7 with PHP5 and I use fcgid and suexec.

I read that some people use PHP-FPM with fastcgi, but I don't know if they are speaking about the old fastcgi or the new fcgid.

Anyway, I want to know if my configuration of fcgid without PHP-FPM is correct or I need to install and configure PHP-FPM to have all the functionality?

Which is the advantage and disadvantage of putting fcgid and PHP-FPM together, in the case that it is correct?

Comment: Which SAPI of PHP are you looking to use? There are several such as PHP-CGI, PHP-FPM, etc... Also it would be helpful to see your configurations.